# Can someone explain how flex-ratio works with iron-flex-layout?

Tags: html, polymer, flexbox, polymer-1.0

According to [Polymer Project's Documentation on flex-layout](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/flex-layout), the below code should produce the image below.

```
<div class="horizontal layout demo">
  <div class="flex-3">Alpha</div>
  <div class="flex">Beta</div>
  <div class="flex-2">Gamma</div>
</div>
```

[image]

It says that "For example, the following examples make "Gamma" 2x larger than "Beta" and "Alpha" 3x larger, use flex-2 and flex-3, respectively."

I'm confused because as you can see from the image, Alpha and Gamma are the same size, and Beta just fills up the space in between. Can someone please explain?

Comment: I think you have to use `class="flex flex-3"` and `class="flex flex-2"` instead of just `class="flex-3"` and `class="flex-2"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs demo apparently has a bug, but the explanatory text before that is correct. To use the flex factors (i.e., `flex-2`, `flex-3`, etc), make sure to include the `iron-flex-factors` [style module](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#style-modules) in your component's style like this:

```
<dom-module id="x-foo">
  <template>
    <style include="iron-flex-factors"></style>
    ...
```

The container `<div>` uses `horizontal` and `layout` classes, which are defined in the `iron-flex` style module, so we also include that in our component's style:

```
<dom-module id="x-foo">
  <template>
    <style include="iron-flex-factors iron-flex"></style>
    ...
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo'
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.9.3/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <style include="iron-flex iron-flex-factors">
        div {
          border: solid 1px blue;
        }
      </style>

      <div class="horizontal layout">
        <div class="flex-3"><p>flex-3</p></div>
        <div class="flex"><p>flex</p></div>
        <div class="flex-2"><p>flex-2</p></div>
      </div>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/PWXEJz?editors=1010)

Comment: Thank you! I was so confused why the documentation was outputting something that looks like that. Your codepen really helped.

Comment: @PritaHasjim No problem :)